# Using react-redux I'm trying to create middleware to do async await logic to be able to use this.props.getUser action function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
> // I get user here with action function which makes call to route

/api/users/$_id
    export const getUser = (_id) => (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(setUsersLoading());
        axios.get(`/api/users/${_id}`)
            .then(res =>
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_USER,
                    payload: res.data
                }))
            .catch(err =>
                dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
            );
    }
    

> // This is my Manage Role Assignment component class

    class ManageRoleAssignment extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
    
            this.state = {
                currentPage: 0,
                roles: "",
                selected: [], // this the state I'm using!
                personnel: []
            }
        }
    
        static propTypes = {
            getUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            **getUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired**, //Prop action function used!
            users: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
            **user: PropTypes.object.isRequired**, //The prop object used!
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.getUsers(); 
    
        }
    
        handleChange = (e) => {
        let target = e.target
        let name = target.name
        let value = Array.from(target.selectedOptions, option => option.value)
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })

       
    }

> I'm calling the this.props.getUser here in the onSubmit

        onSubmit = (e) => { 
        console.log("SELECTED", this.state.selected)
        console.log("PERSONNEL", this.state.personnel)
        //let { user } = this.props.user
        this.props.getUser(this.state.selected)

        console.log("USER", this.props.user)
        e.preventDefault();
        }
```

> The beginning of my render function for the class

```
        render() {
        let { users } = this.props.users
        const { currentPage } = this.state
        this.pageSize = 1;
        this.pagesCount = Math.ceil(10 / this.pageSize)
    
        return (
            <div>
                <Container className="list">
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <ListGroup>
```

> This is the beginning of my multi select element where the users are
> selected for the this.state.selected state

```
                            <h5>Select 1 or more users.</h5>
                            <select size="2" value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleChange}
                                style={{ width: 265 + 'px', fontSize: 20 + 'px' }} name="selected" id="users" multiple>
                                {users.map(({ _id, name, email, role }) => (
                                    <option value={_id}>
                                        {name}
                                    </option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                        </ListGroup>
                        <br />
                        <br />
```

> This is where I'm going to be selecting the role for the users, it
> just list roles

```
                        <h5>Select a role to assign.</h5>
                        <select value={this.state.personnel} onChange={this.handleChange}
                            style={{ width: 265 + 'px', fontSize: 20 + 'px' }} name="personnel">
                            {Object.keys(Role).map(r => <option value={r}>{Role[r]}</option>)}
                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <Button style={{ marginLeft: 100 + 'px' }}>Submit </Button>
                    </form>
                    <Container className="personnelTable">
                        <Table size="sm" striped >
                            <thead>
                                <tr >
                                    <th><h5>Name</h5></th><th><h5>Email</h5></th><th><h5>Role</h5></th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
```

> This is where I'm listing the value for testing purpose which is the
> _id of the users that were selected from the multi selelect element above

```
                            {this.state.selected.map(value => (
                                <tr>
                                    {value}
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                        </Table>
                        <TablePagination
                            currentPage={currentPage}
                            pagesCount={this.pagesCount}
                            handlePageClick={this.handlePageClick}
                        />
                    </Container>
                </Container>

            </div >
        )
    }

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    users: state.users,
    user: state.users
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUsers, getUser })((ManageRoleAssignment))
```

Comment: I'm simply trying to update the state "selected" with the the options clicked in the multiple select element.  The value is the id of the user.  I use the action function from userActions "this.props.getUser" along with the value "_id" to actually get the user in the handleChange.  It updates the "selected" state with space with first click then each click after that it starts to update the state with previous click option being one off...I appreciate anyone could understand and help me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that my initialization of the state will not allow me to add to the state without being removed. I initialize the state with an empty array, but can't get around that empty space.  I've tried setState with a new array and it's not doing the job.  I've tried to different ways to add to the state and then using setState to update.  Any help is highly appreciated..

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange.  Can you please [edit] your question, and add your two comments to the question, in the correct place, so people won't have to check the comments for the full explanation of what you've done.  Thanks.

Comment: Please also choose a better title.